# How to force display of x- and y-axis for each subplot in plotly.express

Tags: python, plotly, histogram, subplot

I want to plot a histogram with row and colum facets using `plotly.express.histogram()` where each subplot gets its own x- and y-axis (for better readability). When looking at the [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/facet-plots/) (e.g. go to section "Histogram Facet Grids") I can see a lot of examples where the x- and y-axes are repeated. But in my case, this somehow is not done automatically.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# create a dummy dataframe with lots of variables
rng = np.random.default_rng(42)
n_vars = 3
n_samples = 10
random_vars = [rng.normal(size=n_samples) for v in range(n_vars)]
m = np.vstack(random_vars).T
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('a','b'),('a','c'),('b','c')],names=['src','tgt'])
df = pd.DataFrame(m,columns=columns)

# convert to long format
df_long = df.melt()

# plot with plotly
fig = px.histogram(df_long,x='value',facet_row='src',facet_col='tgt')
fig.update_layout(yaxis={'side': 'left'})
fig.show()
```

which gives me:

[image]

How do I post-hoc configure the figure so that the x- and y-axis are shown for each subplot?

Answer (score 6):

All you need to do is to customize each y and x axis by:

```
fig.for_each_yaxis(lambda y: y.update(showticklabels=True,matches=None))
fig.for_each_xaxis(lambda x: x.update(showticklabels=True,matches=None))
```

**Output**
[image]